# How do you pass a reference to type 'class'?

Tags: java

I have a method that registers classes for serialization. I want to call this from a control class, something like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Registrar.RegisterClass(Control.SomeRequest);
        Registrar.RegisterClass(Control.SomeResponse);

        Sender testServer = new Sender();
        Receiver testClient = new Receiver();

        testServer.StartServer();
        testClient.StartClient();
    }

    public static class SomeRequest {
        public String text;
    }
    public static class SomeResponse {
        public String text;
    }
---------------------------------------------
public class Registrar {
    static Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();

    public static void RegisterClass(??? cls){
        kryo.register(cls.class);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I could pass in `Control.SomeRequest.class` just as easy, though I'm not sure how to achieve either of these.

Comment: `cls` should probably be an `Object` and you should probably call `getClass()` on it.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. You want to pass `Control.SomeRequest.class` as an argument for `RegisterClass`?

Comment: Just use the `Class` type.

Answer (score 3):

The class name of "classes" is `Class`

```
public static void RegisterClass(Class cls){
        kryo.register(cls);
}
```